# MSAccess and SQL Server Backend, Compare and Update production database schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, vbscript, ms-access-2007

I am running an MSACCESS 2007 front end database with a SQLEXpress back end, this is for a university research project. So cheap/free is good, as is my dev time (free).....

I would like a T-sql (or vbscript) to compare and update the production database.

I am working in a development database making changes and want a simple way for the changes in dev to be propogated into Prod. Unfortunately I am not available to manually update production.

So i think the process would be:

1) Restore Dev to prod sql server
2) Compare Prod vs Dev database (Schema only)
3) Update Prod to equal Dev (Schema only)
4) Check with Step 2.

Option 2:

Compare Generate SQL scripts locally using a database compare to:
Run the SQL scripts

No data entry at this stage

I am aware of the DB compare tools (by Red-Gate)

Anyhow, thanks for any pointers.

Roger

Comment: A cheaper option than redgate is the Microsoft SSDT... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

Comment: What kind of changes to the back-end or front-end? If these are changes to the back-end, do you want to run code through MS Access to update prod? If not, the MS Access tag is not really relevant.

Comment: Thanks...I would prfer the click a button in the access front end and away it goes.  But I accept that may not be possible. The real issue is that I do not always have access to the 'DB sever'. So not being a real developer I was trying to figure this out.  although #podiluska tool looks interesting.

Comment: You can create pass-though queries in MS Access, you can also use ADO and build up a list of DDL scripts to run when you next have access to the server. It all sounds a little dicey.